# Azure Verified ID stuck at publishing - where logs?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/verifiable-credentials-configure-tenant?WT.mc_id=EM-MVP-5002871) to setup Entra Verified ID. I am creating the Verified ID for my subscription. The domain is already verified in AAD as custom domain name. When I try the registration of the domain for the Verified ID it's stuck at publishing.

I have uploaded the did-configuration.json in the suggested location https://example.com/.well-known/did-configuration.json and I can see it with this address on browser. The domain does not forward.

[image]

I checked back after 3 hours but was still publishing.
Where can I see the logs for errors in this publishing process with Verified ID to find a solution?

Not sure if related to stuck at publishing but I have noticed that every time I click on "Verify" as per snap above to see if I can refresh the verification status, the linked_dids changes! I wonder then that I can't click on Verify again until the 3 hours have passed and hope I can refresh verification when I click (if it has not finished I'd have to re-upload the json file with the new lined_dids?)

EDIT: Add Authenticator showing verified domain despite it's still not verified in VerifiedID:

[image]

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an **Azure KeyVault** with required key permissions and passed the values for Verified ID:

[image]

**To verify the Trusted Domain**, need to create and verify DID Registration and Domain ownership verification.

Make sure to Host the **`json`** file in the `https://xxxx/.well-known/did-configuration.json` location on your server and verify domains ownership.

[image]

[image]

And Register the DID, by hosting the **`json`** file in the `https://xxx/.well-known/did.json`

[image]

[image]

I am able to successfully **Register DID and verify ownership** like below:

[image]

**Note** that The Registration status is set to Registered if access is verified.

- Instead of using Azure Portal to create Verified ID, try performing the same using [Home - Microsoft Entra admin center](https://entra.microsoft.com/#home) and check.
- Try clearing cache and perform this operation by logging into Azure Portal via Incognito window to avoid cache related issues.
- You can also try creating a Static Web app with **`did.json`** and **`did-configuration.json`** files and add your domain, use a `CNAME` routed to Azure static URL.
- ***If still the issue persists***, try doing it from the scratch, by deleting it like below:

[image]

**References:**

[Microsoft Entra -Verified ID by Atul Raizada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNIY5hcObd0)

[Azure AD Verifiable Credentials - Troubleshooting tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg2CdDNlD_I)

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini I followed these steps 3 times, I also tried with an Azure static URL from storage but didn't work. Does it work for you with ION trust system which I am using? What is also unexpected behaviour in my case is that when issuing a verified credential, the domain is trusted by the Authenticator app as if it has been verified, despite Verified ID says domain still publishing/not verified.

Comment: Can you check if this helps https://derkvanderwoude.medium.com/microsoft-entra-verified-id-sample-setup-and-deployment-dd65c5508b4f?

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini , I will check but I wanted to let you know that I've added the verified domain screenshots to this post as per prior comment.